# Computer running on Debian 12 now only turns on in tty1 mode and I cannot access the GUI

Tags: debian, intel, datascience-anaconda

I have an ASUS ZenBook 14, and I have been running it on stable Debian (now 12 Bookworm), and GNOME destop environment since I bought it. It has never given me any problems.

But today after installing the platform Anaconda (though I am not completely sure this was the cause) this way:

```
bash /home/"username"/Downloads/Anaconda3-2023.07-Linux-86_64.sh
```

then I updated and upgraded the system in the usual way (`sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade`). After turning off and later on the conputer, the system broke and the computer no longer turns on in the normal way.

Now I am stuck in the "tty1" mode and due to some error I can use the terminal but no other interfaces are available. When running `startx`, a black screen appears with a mouse on it. I can move the mouse, but nothing more.

I think the "AE_NOT_FOUND" note that appears on the screen when turning on is important. As I am quite sure that wasn't there before.

How can I fix this?

I will share the photos of my computer to see if you can find the clues that could fix my problem.

Thank you very much in advance!
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, I have  edited the question.

Comment: Yes I can log in with the terminal. When running startx, a black screen appears with the mouse on it.

Comment: What does `apt policy gnome` show?

Comment: After upgrading from bullseye to bookworm and having to upgrade some packages manually, something went wrong and I ended up only having access to tty1 mode also. Installing manually `sudo apt install gdm3` got me the GUI back.